# own css file not loading

Tags: jsf

I'm configuring a project with primefaces 6.1

My problem is that when I am trying to do this the `sample.css` is not loading

[image]

update:

I tried to do something like :

```
<h:body>
<h:outputStylesheet name="/resources/css/sample.css" />
...
</h:body>

<h:body>
<h:outputStylesheet name="/css/sample.css" />
...
</h:body>

<h:body>
    <f:facet name="last">
    <h:outputStylesheet name="/resources/css/sample.css" /> 
    </f:facet>
  ....
</h:body>
```

my css file

```
sample.css


  #box{   
        width:170px;
        height:120px;
        margin:2px 10px 20px 10px;
    }
```

Comment: Code in text please, not in images. And please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used/11988418

Comment: Probably path to sample.css is unknown.

Comment: i tried with name="css/sample.css" but is not working

Comment: And this is not PrimeFaces css, but your own CSS